How to prevent page to scroll on top when user add a comment on post?
i am trying to make website using Laravel 10 and i have added comment option for users so they can leave comment on any post but the problem is when use add comment on post the page scroll to top even if user leave comment on 20th post. so it is difficult for use ro go back where he left..
this is my code for add comment
@auth
    <div class="comment-box mt-2">
        <form id="commentForm" action="{{ route('comments.store') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{$post->id}}">
            <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
            <div class="position-relative mt-4">
                <textarea name="content" placeholder="leave a comment" required class="form-control" style="padding-right: 30px; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" class="position-absolute" style="border: none; background: none; right: 10px; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">
                    <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endauth

and this is script
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#commentForm').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

            // Collect form data
            var formData = $(this).serialize();

            // Debugging: Log form data to ensure it is correct
            console.log('Form data:', formData);

            // Perform the AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: formData,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // Debugging: Log the response from the server
                    console.log('Server response:', data);

                    // Handle successful form submission (e.g., display a success message)
                    // Optionally, clear the textarea or display the new comment
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    // Debugging: Log any error from the server
                    console.error('Error:', error);

                    // Handle form submission errors
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

i have tried various method from online and AI but still not works..

"this is my code for add comment" - and that presumably gets output multiple times on the same page? Then you would of course have a problem with duplicate IDs. (Most likely any of these forms apart from the first one, submit the normal way then, and not via your submit handler - and that would of course explain why you end up at the top of the page again - because it is actually a new page, loaded as result of the form submission.)

It sounds like the page is reloading even though you are posting the comment using AJAX. Maybe, for some reason, the the call back function of your submit event is not running and the form will just do an ordinary POST request -- can you look into that?

Since this form appears once per post, you could use the post's id write the ids.
@auth
  <div class="...">
    <form id="comment-form-{{ $post->id }}" action="{{ route('comments.store') }}" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <input type="hidden" id="comment-input-{{ $post-id }}-post-id" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}">
      <input type="hidden" id="comment-input-{{ $post-id }}-user-id" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
      <div class="...">
        <textarea id="comment-input-{{ $post-id }}-content" name="content" placeholder="leave a comment" required class="..." style="..."></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="..." style="...">
          <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
@endauth

$('[id^="comment-form-"]').on('submit', function (event) { ... });


You can handle the success response.
Add this code in the success response:
var newComment = `
                    <div class="comment">
                        <p>${data.content}</p>
                        <small>Posted by: ${data.user.name}</small>
                    </div>
                 `;
$('.comment-box').append(newComment);
                
// Optionally, clear the textarea
$('#commentForm textarea[name="content"]').val('');


IDs must be unique, so the on('submit', ) is probably only applied to the first form if any. That is why the page reloads when you submit the following forms. They just perform an ordinary POST request.
In this example I add the event listener to the parent element of all the forms. The e.target in the callback function is always a form, so you don't need IDs on all the forms. If you just stick to the name attribute on both form elements and on all form fields it doesn't matter, because the names does not have to be unique.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let posts_section = document.getElementById('posts');
  posts_section.addEventListener('submit', posts_section_submit_handler);
});


function posts_section_submit_handler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form));
  //fetch(form.action, {
  fetch('data:application/json,{"status":"OK"}', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': form._token.value
      },
      method: form.method,
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Server response:', data);
    });
}
<section id="posts">
  <div class="comment-box mt-2">
    <form name="commentForm" action="/comments" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="qwerty">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1">
      <div class="position-relative mt-4">
        <textarea name="content" placeholder="leave a comment" required class="form-control" style="padding-right: 30px; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="position-absolute" style="border: none; background: none; right: 10px; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">⮕</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-box mt-2">
    <form name="commentForm" action="/comments" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="qwerty">
      <input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="1">
      <div class="position-relative mt-4">
        <textarea name="content" placeholder="leave a comment" required class="form-control" style="padding-right: 30px; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="position-absolute" style="border: none; background: none; right: 10px; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">⮕</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>



